# What's the easiest website registration process?

Tags: registration, user-expectation, workflow

Are there other ways of confirming a user registration other than a confirmation email? I'm finding a lot of confirmation emails are getting sent to users junk mail folders and flooding our customer service with calls.

Current solution is to simply ask for email twice in the form and not bother sending out the confirmation and validation email.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just stick with convention and use the "confirm email address" method?

Comment: Might it also be worth displaying a message to the user after the form is submitted to say something along the lines of "please check your spam folder if the email does not appear within X minutes"?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by your website registration process?  Are you trying to gather information on your users?  Guarantee that this is their only account on your site?  Authenticate that they are who they say they are?

Comment: If there is any possible way to not require registration at all then you've just made billions of potential users. Henry is asking all the right questions.

Comment: "I'm not here to be in a relationship!"  --  http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button

Comment: Trying to gather information on our users and have the ability to communicate back with them on product updates, etc. We tried the "no registration process" for a while where people could simply be users and have no requirement to register. However, business objectives have changed from the higher ups.

Comment: I should add too that there is still an option to be a user without registering. I'm just trying to make sure those who do opt in to register are taken through the simplest method possible.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to use OAuth to leverage one or more social network authentication services.  These social networks have already taken the user through the email confirmation process.  It is a complicated process for you, the programmer, but many CRM's and cloud services have ways of making it much easier.
Meanwhile, it is simplicity incarnate for your users because they use the same credentials to get on your site as they do to get on facebook or twitter.  You never see those credentials, but you can get other information from the social network's database, allowing you to personalize each visitor's experience of your site.  Best yet, if the visitor changes their credentials on the social network, your site automatically accepts the new credentials, all without the additional burden of keeping track of the visitor's information.